# metaquery having same metakey with multiple value

Tags: php, search, dynamic, model, narrowing

I want to show the records which are having  `"modelyear
between 2003 to 2006  and   modelyear between 2007 to 2009  AND  price
between 1 lakh to 3 lakh  and   price  between 3 lakh  to 5 lakh"` MEANS records having modelyear between 2003 to 2009 and price between 1 lakh to 5 lakh like in jabong.com narrow search.

I used the following (*see below*). But it's not working.

Could someone suggested, how to solve it in **wordpress meta query**? Please!

```
<?php 
$args2=array(
'posts_per_page' => 100,
'post_type' => 'product',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query' => array(
'relation' => 'AND',
array(
'key' => 'year',
'value' => array(2003, 2006),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
//'type' => 'DECIMAL',
),
array(
'key' => 'year',
'value' => array(2007, 2009),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
//'type' => 'DECIMAL',
),


array(
'key' => '_price',
'value' => array(1, 3),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
//'type' => 'DECIMAL',
),
array(
'key' => '_price',
'value' => array(3, 5),
'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
//'type' => 'DECIMAL',
),

),
);
?>
```

Comment: This code is not in a database language, it just defines an array. You'll need to provide the name of the framework you are using if people are going to be able to help you (and probably a good deal more). Having said that I think I can see wordpress in there, so you may find this helpful: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: yes i want to solve it in wordpress meta query